# XGetWindowProperty returning BadWindow

Tags: c, x11, xlib

i'm getting the focused window from `XGetInputFocus()` and feeding it into `XGetWindowProperty()` to check if a window has the `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN` Atom

but when i close a fullscreen window like a game such as team fortress 2 or a media player like mpv `XGetWindowProperty` fails with error

X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter).

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    Display* d = XOpenDisplay(0);
    XEvent ev;
    Atom windowprop;    
    Atom actualType;
    int format;
    unsigned long numItems, bytesAfter;
    unsigned char *data = NULL;
    Atom netwmstate = XInternAtom(d, "_NET_WM_STATE", True);
    Atom netwmstatefullscreen = XInternAtom (d, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN", True);
    Window focus;
    int revert_to = RevertToParent;
    int result;

  XSelectInput (d, RootWindow(d, DefaultScreen(d)), SubstructureNotifyMask);    
  while (1)
  {
    XNextEvent(d, &ev);
            XGetInputFocus(d, &focus, &revert_to);
            result = XGetWindowProperty(d,
                                    focus,
                                    netwmstate,
                                    0L,
                                    (~0L),
                                    False,
                                    AnyPropertyType,
                                    &actualType,
                                    &format,
                                    &numItems,
                                    &bytesAfter,
                                    &data);
            if (result == Success && data){
                windowprop = ((Atom *)data)[0];
                if (windowprop==netwmstatefullscreen){
                    system("xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -s false");
                    printf("Disabled compositing\n");
                    }
                else {
                    system("xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -s true");
                    printf("enabled compositing\n");
                    }
            }

  }
}
```

Comment: I assume this code is running in the background while you open, focus and close other screens? Is there a chance the current focus becomes invalid between `XGetInputFocus()` and `XgetWindowProperty()`? I.e., a race condition occurs?

Comment: *when i close a fullscreen window* Adding to the comment @Evert made, I'd say there's a good chance that the window was destroyed by the time you run `XGetWindowProperty()`.  You *are* closing windows...

Comment: @AndrewHenle right now i think i'm looping it any time an XEvent is recieved. is there a way to make it only continue when the focus value is updated instead.

Comment: @Roman  Look at the events you're receiving - I suspect you'll see the window getting destroyed in the event stream.  If that's what's happening - the window gets destroyed before you can get the properties - there's not really much you can do. You might also need to check the return value from `XGetInputFocus()`